# Convex conjugate and subdifferential of a function taking values in $\mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a normed vector space and $\varphi:E \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$.

- The *domain* of $\varphi$ is defined as $D(\varphi) := \{x \in E : \varphi(x) \neq \pm\infty\}$. The map $\varphi$ is said to be *proper* if $D(\varphi) \neq \emptyset$.
- The *convex conjugate* $\varphi^*:E^* \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ is defined as
  $$
  \varphi^* (f) := \sup_{x \in E} \{f(x) -\varphi (x)\} \quad \forall f \in E^*.
  $$
- The *subdifferential* of $\varphi$ at $x$ is defined as
  $$
  \partial \varphi(x) := \left\{f \in E^* : f(y-x) + \varphi (x) \le \varphi(y) \quad \forall y \in E\right\}.
  $$

We adopt the usual conventions that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$,

- $+\infty + \alpha = +\infty$ and $-\infty + \alpha = -\infty$, and
- $$
  +\infty \cdot \alpha =
  \begin{cases}
  0 &\text{if} & \alpha=0, \\
  +\infty &\text{if} & \alpha>0, \\
  -\infty &\text{if} & \alpha<0.
  \end{cases}
  \quad \text{and} \quad
  -\infty \cdot \alpha =
  \begin{cases}
  0 &\text{if} & \alpha=0, \\
  +\infty &\text{if} & \alpha<0, \\
  -\infty &\text{if} & \alpha>0.
  \end{cases}
  $$

**Remark** If $\varphi \equiv +\infty$ then $D(\varphi) = \emptyset$, $\varphi^* \equiv -\infty$, and $\partial \varphi (x) = E^*$ for all $x \in E$.

I want to prove below results, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $\varphi:E \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ and $(x, f)\in E \times E^*$.
>
> 1. $f \in \partial \varphi(x)  \iff \varphi^{*}(f) = f(x) -\varphi(x)$.
> 2. If $\varphi$ is proper then $f \in \partial \varphi(x)  \iff \varphi^{*}(f) + \varphi(x)=f(x)$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**My attempt:**

It's possible that $\varphi^{*}(f)$ and $\varphi(x)$ are both infinite, so we keep them separately on each side of the (in)equalities. This is to avoid the un-defined $(+\infty) + (-\infty)$ and $(-\infty) + (+\infty)$.

1.

We have $\varphi^* (f) = \sup_{y \in E} \{ f(y) \rangle - \varphi (y)\}$, so $\varphi^* (f) \ge f(x) - \varphi (x)$.

- Let $f \in \partial \varphi(x)$, i.e., $f(y-x) + \varphi (x) \le \varphi (y)$ for all $y\in E$. Then
  $$
  f(y) - \varphi (y) \le f(x) - \varphi (x) \quad \forall y \in E.
  $$
  So $\varphi^* (f) \le f(x)- \varphi (x)$. Hence $\varphi^* (f) = f(x) - \varphi (x)$.
- Let $\varphi^{*}(f) = f(x) -\varphi(x)$. Then $f(x) -\varphi(x) \ge f(y) - \varphi (y)$ for all $y \in E$. So $f(y-x)  + \varphi (x) \le \varphi (y)$ for all $y\in E$. Hence $y \in \partial \varphi (x)$.

2. 

Because $\varphi$ is proper, there is $a \in D(\varphi)$, i.e., $\varphi (a) < +\infty$. Also, $\varphi^* \neq -\infty$.

- Let $f \in \partial \varphi (x)$. Then $f(a-x) + \varphi (x) \le \varphi (a)$, so $\varphi (x) < +\infty$.
- Let $\varphi^{*}(f)  + \varphi(x)=f(x)$. Then $\varphi^* (f), \varphi (x) \neq \pm\infty$.

The claim then follows from (1). This completes the proof.